# Weight of a gas measured in Space and other planets of Solar System

Tags: planet, space, gas

I searched for [how measure gas weight](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+measure+gas+weight&client=ms-android-lava&prmd=visn&sxsrf=ALeKk01nuaTQSB2skqyF1QKlDa9FM8cl7w:1622522636110&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiowvXqz_XwAhWdxjgGHUCaAisQ_AUoAnoECAIQAg&biw=360&bih=592&dpr=2) and about [gases in space](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=gases+in+space&sxsrf=ALeKk02WIYp_RtKmt4TPjhoqbWTnC8BBgQ%3A1622523588367&source=hp&ei=xL61YK-QFOiC4-EP9OiosAo&oq=&gs_lcp=ChFtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1ocBABGAAyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwgjEOoCECcyBwguEOoCECc6BQgAEJECOgoILhDHARCvARBDOgQIABBDOggILhCxAxCDAToFCC4QsQNQ9qwBWLLCAWCJzgFoAnAAeACAAZACiAGQApIBAzItMZgBAKABAbABDw&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-hp)

https://www.shutterstock.com/search/space+gases

https://education.seattlepi.com/gases-found-outer-space-5888.html

Will the weight of gas measurement in space as well as in other planets of the Solar system be different as compared to gas measurement on Planet Earth?

Comment: Are you aware of the difference between weight and [mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass) ?

Comment: Please use the editor properly to insert a link.   There is help provided in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weight is a property of mass which you can experience only when on the solid surface of a gravitating body - but not when you are in free fall. Yet even in free fall you retain your mass. Weight is the force the mass exerts on a scale (in the presence of and proportional to the strenght of a gravity field which pushes the mass onto that scale - which requires that neither is in free fall).

Mass itself is the fundamental property of any particle itself - independent of how much other mass is in its vicinity, thus independent of external gravity field around.

See also the wikipedia article on the [distinction of mass and weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_versus_weight).